# how to convert time stamp 07 Mar 2016 01:00:03 PM to numeric in r

Tags: r, timestamp

Im trying to find time difference between two timestamps, say, start and endtime. But the stamps are in  string format :07 Mar 2016 01:00:03 PM. Can someone help how to convert this in numeric and find the time difference? Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work? Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 5):

lubridate is your new best friend so download it right away to get to know her.

```
install.packages('lubridate')
library(lubridate)
```

Based on your example, use dmy_hms()

```
a <- dmy_hms('07 Mar 2016 01:00:03 PM')
# "2016-03-07 13:00:03 UTC"
b <- dmy_hms('08 Mar 2016 01:00:03 PM')
# "2016-03-08 13:00:03 UTC"
```

Then a simple subtraction could get the date diff.

```
b - a
# Time difference of 1 days
```

Or you can also use the as.numeric() use this number for calculation later.

```
as.numeric(b - a)
# 1
```

Comment: Giving you a vote just for your hilarious opening sentence.